# Eclipse Neon: How to setup JavaEE and Javascript in one IDE

Tags: eclipse

The Neon version has separate packages for JavaEE and Javascript development. Is there a way to have a single IDE and still have both the features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just open 'Help > Install New Software...'.

Choose the main Neon site (`http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon`)

Find the tools you want (probably in the 'Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development' section) and install them.

Additional tools are on the Web Tools Project specific site `http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/neon`

Comment: No, the tools aren't in there

Comment: Thanks, selected this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Java EE package actually includes all content from JavaScript package. So just pick the Java EE one and you should get everything you need.